# Unable to read json file and print output

Tags: python

```
user = {}
max_length = 4

while len(user) < max_length:
  name = input("What is your name? ")
  food= input("What is your favourite food?  ")
  user[name]= food 
  users = json.dumps(user)  

  if name.lower() == 'q' or food.lower()== 'q':
    break

with open('users.json', 'a') as outfile:
    outfile.write(f"{users.title()}\n")

  
with open('users.json') as outfile:
  user= json.load(outfile) - **the code fails here** 
 
print(user)
```

The while loop runs a user input with two questions, and the answers are placed in a dictionary that are placed in a dictionary in a json file. I want to read this file and print the output in the terminal but I keep getting an error. I'm not sure how to fix this because everything I've tried isn't working.

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 53, in <module>
    json.load(outfile)
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 32 (char 31)
 
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: You can't write extra arbitrary data to a json file.  (Well, you _can_, but then it's not a json file anymore, and attempting to read it as a json file will fail, in exactly this way.)

Comment: JSON has a specific file format and this does not match the format. Maybe try `json.dump(user, outfile)` to the file instead?

Comment: You can't do this: `outfile.write(f"{users.title()}\n")`. The error raises in the line you say, but it is generated with this sentence because it writes a non json file, so trying to read it as json raises the error.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are adding data to a JSON file in a non-JSON format. To keep this consistent, I recommend using `json.dump` for placing the data in the file too.

Edit: when you define the first user, store the data as a dictionary, but *inside an array*. That way, you can append to it later on. Still, you will need to read and then write the whole array to the outfile. Appending to the file won't work the way that is intended here. This works well for text files, not JSON as far as I know.

```
with open("users.json") as reader:
    all_users = json.load(reader)

all_users.append(user)
```

Then completely rewrite to the file.

```
with open("users.json","w") as outfile:
    json.dump(user,outfile)
```

This does assume that `user` is in a valid JSON format, though.

Comment: It still doesnt work because it was unable to load multiple dictionaries so I changed it to an array and I'm still getting the same error :/

Comment: I just realized you are appending to the file. You may need to read the contents of the file and overwrite it instead. I'll update my answer when I can with a small example.